# Android Compose Constraint Layout Issue

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a Compable function that is composed of 1 column that contains 11 rows. Each row contains a Text and a Button. In the first row I can position each object. I copy the code to the second row (also changing each objects "name") and get errors:
CreateRefs -can't be called in this context
constraintAs (both) - can't be called in this context.

I have a sense that a Row() is not considered a parent.
What is the proper approach considering my a column with multable rows?

Comment: If failed to enclose the second row with -  ConstraintLayout... So now no errors but even though both are in different rows - they overlay eachl other..

Comment: then it should be removed, as it not reproducible/caused by a typo, and not gonna help anyone else

Answer (score -1):

It's my error, I failed to wrap the second rows contents with a
ConstraintLayout(...){}
Now I get no errors, but the second row overlays the first row
I'm going to mark this as closed.
Thanks for your attetio